# add class on li remove after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using jquery to add the class to active css on "li" and also navigate to an html page.but after page navigates the class disappers on "li". I have tried different ways to resolve this but couldn't get the point.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( '#topList ul li' ).click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));


        if($(this).attr('id') == "add") {            
            document.location.href = 'localhost:8080/add';
            $(this).attr('id').addClass("active");            
        }
    });    
});
```

here is the menu list, what I want is when I click on li it should call a page add and also add a class on that li.

html code

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="" id="add"><a href="javascript:void(0);"  ><i class="add"></i> Add</a>      </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Sorry for that I have edited the question. Pleae check now

Comment: You said `hover` state but you're using `click` event!

Comment: Anyway, I believe you should use this: `$(this).addClass("active")`.

Comment: I have also tried with $(this) but no use, because before that I am also calling an html page. May be I should do it like that to have this id on that navigated page then add the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following script on the page where you have menu or the links.

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<a href="blah blah" > Test page</a>
<a href="blah blah" > Test page</a>
</div>





   $(document).ready(function () {
                var pageTitle = window.location.pathname.replace(/^.*\/([^/]*)/, "$1");

                $('#cssmenu a').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).attr('href').toLowerCase() == pageTitle.toLocaleLowerCase())
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                });



            });
```

Comment: OK. then how to navigate a page at the same time?

Comment: You can use the same code as you already did for redirect. this is just for control the active class on active page. see the updated answer.

Comment: I used your only window.location.pathname.replace line of code and it worked, so no use of below code. :). Thankyou. I used this code in my if conditions and the hrefs were already emebeded in the html. Rest the if's will work with your this line of code window.location.pathname. Thanks once again.

Comment: np. Glad to know it worked for you. i will edit it to remove the extra codes,

Comment: For some reason mine isn't working :/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392223/how-to-show-or-hide-tab-based-on-the-page-url

Answer (score 2):

You need to add class for the li in the page you are calling ie, the page will be rendered when you call **localhost:8080/add**. 
Because in your code setting up of active class wont be called since the **localhost:8080/add** will start loading in the previous line of code `(document.location.href = 'localhost:8080/add';)`

If the page to be rendered is static page then, add this code in that page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#add').addClass("active"); 
});
```

Comment: OK, but how to solve it ? Can you give him some explanation ?

Comment: I know that that this is the case, but how to solve this? that calling a url and adding a class on li.

Comment: the you are rendering is a static html page?

Comment: is $(this) will be recognizable on that page?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem on [my website](http://paulwilliams.biz) by looking at the URL and deciding which of the navigation elements was best to add.

```
function showContent(target) {
    var e = $('#'+target);
    $(".content").hide();
    $("#nav li.active").removeClass("active");
    $("#nav li[target='"+target+"']").addClass("active");
    e.toggle();
    ga('send','pageview',window.location.pathname+"#"+target);
}

// this looks at the URL (by the #...) and decides which view is active
// this gets called on ready and if the client hits the link 
//   (which dynamically loads instead of making a trip for a new page to the server)
$(window).hashchange(function() {
    var which=window.location.hash.substring(1);
    switch( which) {
    default:
        which="profile";
    case "profile":
    case "resume":
    case "projects":
    case "contact":
        showContent( which);
    }
});
```